# Is it necessary to give a \\ before \intertext?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath

I am not sure which one is correct when using `\intertext` or `\shortintertext`. Adding `\\` before them or not.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section*{Without a line break }
\begin{gather*}
E = mc^2
\intertext{Multiply both side by 2, we have}
2E = 2mc^2
\end{gather*}

\section*{With a line break}
\begin{gather*}
E = mc^2\\
\intertext{Multiply both side by 2, we have}
2E = 2mc^2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't see any differences. Or there is something wrong with my eyes. So the question is: *Is it necessary to give a `\\` before `\intertext` or `\shortintertext`?*

Comment: According to `amsmath` documentation: "`\intertext` may only appear right after a ``\\`` or ``\\*`` command", but it seems to work without as well...

Comment: @karlkoeller: That is why I am always confused with it when writing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `\intertext` to work, it has to be in vertical mode, which means it should follow `\\`. However, `\intertext` does a check to see whether this is the case (...`\ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi`...). If not, it attempts to insert it. As such, the use of it may be considered cautiously optional.

From the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.pdf) (p 33 onward):

> The `\intertext` command is used for inserting text between the rows
>   of an alignment. It might better be done as an environment, but the
>   `\begingroup` from `\begin` would cause the `\noalign` to fail.
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\intertext}{\@amsmath@err{\Invalid@@\intertext}\@eha}
> ```
>
> `\intertext@` is called by all environments that allow the use of the
>   `\intertext` command.
>
> ```
> \def\intertext@{%
>   \def\intertext##1{%
> ```
>
> If current mode is not vmode, the most likely reason is that the
>   writer forgot the `\\` that is supposed to precede `\intertext`. All
>   right, then, let's try adding it our ownself. But, to be slightly
>   careful: `\\` does a futurelet, and it's slightly dangerous to allow a
>   letted token to barge around loose in our internal code when it has
>   been let to a conditional token like `\fi`. So let's interpose
>   something in front of the `\fi` for the futurelet to take instead.
>   (And careful again: it has to be something evanescent, not (e.g.)
>   `\relax` which would cause the next halign cell to fire up and keep
>   `\noalign` from working.)
>
> ```
>     \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
>     \noalign{%
>       \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
>       \vbox{\normalbaselines
> ```
>
> We need to do something extra if the outside environment is a list
>   environment. I don't see offhand an elegant way to test "are we inside
>   any list environment" that is both easy and reliable (for example,
>   checking for zero `\@totalleftmargin` wouldn't catch the case where
>   `\@totalleftmargin` is zero but `\linewidth` is less than
>   `\columnwidth`), so it seems to me checking `\linewidth` is the best
>   practical solution.
>
> ```
>          \ifdim\linewidth=\columnwidth
>          \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
>          \fi
>          \noindent##1\par}%
>        \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
>      }%
> }}
> ```